# windows 7 schedule wifi or script wifi enabled/disabled

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, scheduled-tasks

I would like to be able to enable and disable my wireless connection automatically either through some sort of scheduled task or some simple script that I could cobble together. I'm on windows 7 and I've been unable to turn up very much on such a subject, several for linux but that's not entirely helpful to me.

Example: turn on the wifi at 2am when I'm asleep and Hughsnet lets me use more bandwidth, then turn it back off again at 7 or 8am when Hughsnet dislikes me again.

Is this something I could program or script or is there a windows schedule that could to that directly?